# How to display C# timespan object in 12 hours format in Kendo ui grid in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using time datatype in sqlserver 2008 database to save time.
I want to display this time in Kendo ui grid in mvc 5. 
I can read this in c# with timespan datatype and giving this as json data to the kendo ui grid.
this is the Json response we are getting.

```
"Data":[{
        "CCdate":"\/Date(1418322600000)\/",
        "CCDay":"Friday",
        "Status":true,
        "OpeningHour":{"Hours":10,"Minutes":0,"Seconds":0,"Milliseconds":0,"Ticks":360000000000,"Days":0,"TotalDays":0.41666666666666663,"TotalHours":10,"TotalMilliseconds":36000000,"TotalMinutes":600,"TotalSeconds":36000},
        "ClosingHour":{"Hours":5,"Minutes":0,"Seconds":0,"Milliseconds":0,"Ticks":180000000000,"Days":0,"TotalDays":0.20833333333333331,"TotalHours":5,"TotalMilliseconds":18000000,"TotalMinutes":300,"TotalSeconds":18000}
        }]
```

OpeningHour and ClosingHour are my timespan objects
How do I display these time span objects in kendo ui grid in 12 hour format.

Comment: What do you mean by "12 hour format"?  Timespan display a measure of time (ie a span of time), this is however many days, hours, minutes, seconds, etc..  12 hour format as in am/pm applies only to time of day and makes no sense in a timespan format.  You wouldn't say 1pm hours have passed. when 13 hours have passed.  If you want to display a specific date or time, you would use a DateTime object, not TimeSpan.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, And sorry to ask like this. I want to save store opening and closing hours in database so can I use time type in sql server , timespan in c# and I need to display this in ui as 12: 00 Pm. if no please advice the correct.

Comment: No, you don't use timespan.  I already advised you the correct, why do I have to tell you twice?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

Format your grid column like this,

```
{
  field: "OpeningHour",
  title: "Opening Hour",
  format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt}"
}
```

See this link : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting